# Retrieve job definition of list of jobs listed in the second file

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

I have a file with 250,000 job details. In this source file, all jobs have different parameters, so the number of lines for each job may vary. The only pattern is that each job definition starts with `insert:` and ends at break line.

```
insert: PPC_SA1   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Run program"
std_out_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.log"
std_err_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.err"
alarm_if_fail: 1
group: P
resources:

insert: PPC_SA2   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0

insert: PPC_SA3   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Run program"
std_out_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.log"

insert: PPC_SA4   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Run program"
std_out_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.log"
std_err_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.err"
alarm_if_fail: 1
group: P
resources:

insert: PPC_SA5   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0

insert: PPC_SA6   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Run program"
std_out_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.log"
```

Target jobs:

```
PPC_SA1
PPC_SA5
PPC_SA3
```

I need to extract the entries for those jobs from the list above into another file:

```
insert: PPC_SA1   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Run program"
std_out_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.log"
std_err_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.err"
alarm_if_fail: 1
group: P
resources:

insert: PPC_SA5   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0

insert: PPC_SA3   job_type: CMD
box: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Run program"
std_out_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.log"
```

Comment: Please edit your post to indicate what you already tried and where you ran into problem. That way contributors can understand what tools you have available/are familiar with, and you can avoid receiving proposed solutions that you already know won't work.

Comment: I know simple shell script with help of echo, awk but unable to get results :(

Comment: please note apart from that you can always use your votes, you only can choose **one** of the answers as accepted among all of the answers you received. which indicates it resolved your problem, see see also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the jobs are all ended by an empty line, you can use `perl` in "paragraph mode" (which means that it considers `\n\n`, en empty line, as the record separator, effectively treating "paragraphs" as "lines"):

```
$ perl -00lne 'print if /insert:\s+PPC_SA[153]\s/' file
insert: PPC_SA1   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Run program"
std_out_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.log"
std_err_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.err"
alarm_if_fail: 1
group: P
resources:

insert: PPC_SA3   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Run program"
std_out_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.log"

insert: PPC_SA5   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
```

The `-00` enables paragraph mode, and then the script prints all records that match `insert:\s+PPC_SA` followed by one of `1`, `5` or `3` and another whitespace character.

Of course, that isn't very practical if you have many target ids, so you can also generalize it to:

```
cat file | 
    perl -00lne 'BEGIN{ $k{$_}++ for @ARGV; @ARGV=()} /insert:\s+(\S+)/; print if $k{$1}' PPC_SA1 PPC_SA5 PPC_SA3
```

Or, alternatively, you can use `awk`. Save your target ids in a file (called `target_ids` in this example), one per line, and run:

```
$ awk '(NR==FNR){a[$1]++; next}
       { 
         if(/insert:/ && $2 in a){want=1} 
         if(want){print}
         if(/^\s*$/){want=0}
        }' target_ids file
insert: PPC_SA1   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Run program"
std_out_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.log"
std_err_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.err"
alarm_if_fail: 1
group: P
resources:

insert: PPC_SA3   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Run program"
std_out_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.log"

insert: PPC_SA5   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
```

Comment: Okay, many thanks, let me try on system

Comment: I tried awk way and it worked well, many thanks Terdon, have a great day

Answer (score 4):

what about this?

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ trgtJbs[$0]; next } ($2 in trgtJbs)' targetJobs RS='' allJobs
```

first we read all the targetJobs from the *`targetJobs`* file, then since you mentioned each jobs in the *`allJobs`* file are separated with an empty line, so then we sets the **R**ecord **S**eparator for that second file to an empty line and checking if the second field of each jobs-block was exist in the *`trgtJbs`* array we used, then they will be outputted.

Just in case you wanted to preserve that empty line in output, do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ trgtJbs[$0]; next }
    ($2 in trgtJbs){ print sep $0; sep=ORS }' targetJobs RS='' allJobs
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` in paragraph mode, you can select the records you need:

```
awk -v RS= -v FS='\n' -v ORS='\n\n' '$1~/PPC_SA(1|3|5)[[:space:]]+/' file
insert: PPC_SA1   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Run program"
std_out_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.log"
std_err_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.err"
alarm_if_fail: 1
group: P
resources:

insert: PPC_SA3   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Run program"
std_out_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.log"

insert: PPC_SA5   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

`awk '/insert:\s+PPC_SA[135]\s+/,/^$/' input`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/^insert.* PPC_SA[153]/,/^$/p' filename



output

insert: PPC_SA1   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Run program"
std_out_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.log"
std_err_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.err"
alarm_if_fail: 1
group: P
resources:

insert: PPC_SA3   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Run program"
std_out_file: "/home/PROD/autosys/logs/${AUTO_JOB_NAME}_`date +%y%m%d`.log"

insert: PPC_SA5   job_type: CMD
name: PPC
command: sa
machine: P
owner: cat
permission:
date_conditions: 0
```